# Deploying Grails to the cloud (Jelastic) Bootstrap issue?

Tags: grails, deployment, cloud, bootstrapping, jelastic

I have created a Grails Application and it is well on its way to completion and I had been testing it with various Cloud providers, for example Cloud Foundry, Heroku, App Engine etc. In the end I went for Jelastic as it was the one that seemed to fully support the use of local plug-ins as I only needed to upload a "war" file for deployment.

Up until today I was having no issues with this and everything was fine, however I have made some changes and added some relationships to my application which I then populate using the BootStrap. This Bootstrap worked before however it has now stopped, below you can see an example of my Bootstrap:

```
def init = { servletContext ->

def adminRole = new SecRole(authority: 'ADMIN').save(flush: true) 
def userRole = new SecRole(authority: 'USER').save(flush: true)

def Admin = new SecUser(username: 'admin', email:'admin@admin.com', enabled: true, password: 'password')

def SuperUser = new Areas(name:"SuperUser")
.addToUsers(Admin)
.save(flush:true)

SecUserSecRole.create Admin, adminRole, true

assert SecUser.count() == 1 
assert SecRole.count() == 2 
assert SecUserSecRole.count() == 1 
    }
```

When I run the application locally with this data the BootStrap works fine, however when I run it on Jelastic I get the following error message:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException: Error executing bootstraps; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; SQL
```

This is only a partial Stack-trace of where the error occurs but im at a loss as to why it happens, can someone please help?

Thanks

EDIT.....

I have also tried this bootstrap data with the same error message being displayed :S

```
def init = { servletContext ->

def adminRole = new SecRole(authority: 'ADMIN').save(flush: true) 

def SuperAdmin = new Areas(name: 'Super Admin')

SuperAdmin.save(flush: true)

def area = Areas.findByName('SuperAdmin')

def SuperAdmin = new SecUser(username: 'admin', email:'test@test.com', area: area, enabled: true, password: 'admin')

SuperAdmin.save()

SecUserSecRole.create SuperAdmin, adminRole, true

assert SecUser.count() == 1 
assert SecRole.count() == 2 
assert SecUserSecRole.count() == 1 
    }
```

The error message I am getting is below:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException: Error executing bootstraps; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; SQL [select this_.id as id3_0_, this_.version as version3_0_, this_.account_expired as account3_3_0_, this_.account_locked as account4_3_0_, this_.area_id as area5_3_0_, this_.email as email3_0_, this_.enabled as enabled3_0_, this_."password" as password8_3_0_, this_.password_expired as password9_3_0_, this_.username as username3_0_ from sec_user this_ where this_.username=?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
```

I have stripped out the BootStrap data and the app starts fine, can anyone shed any light on this as it runs fine with the bootstrap locally just not on the cloud? Thanks in advance

Comment: I have updated the question, can anyone help?

Comment: is there no one who can halp with this? is the bootstrap file wrong?

Comment: is there no one who can even offer any advice on this??? I have tried multiple bootstrap methods and this just doesn’t like the relational objects being bootstrapped for some reason :S

Answer (score 1):

I guess the information you've provided is not enough to help you.

In order to debug this, I would suggest that you remove your bootstrap code so that you application will start up.

Next I would install the console plugin (http://grails.org/plugin/console). This will let you test your bootstrap code in the console. Maybe it helps you to track the problem down.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the same environment topology locally as you have in Jelastic cloud?
Could you provide your Jelastic environment name?
Also, make sure your Jelastic installation do not miss DB connection libs and the version is the same to the one you use locally.